# How to make a variable equal to the input received from the input field in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was wondering how to make this code work.I always get 12 in the console.

```
from tkinter import *
s = 12
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Program")
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

def clicked():
    e.get = s
    print(s)

button = Button(root,command=clicked,text="ok")
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you should say `s = e.get()` instead of what you said there

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the function `clicked` as follows:

```
def clicked():
    s=e.get()
    print(s)
```

There were two errors in your code:

1. You were trying to assign the value `12` to a function.
2. You were not calling the function (using parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

this line here:

```
e.get = s
```

says the method of `e` named `get` is equally to `s`.
Which is nonsense. You want `s` to be equally to what is returned by `e.get`.
to have something returned you need to invoke this method first.
So the logical right way to do this is by:

```
s = e.get()
```

Note that it is a variable in the enclosed namespaces of your function.
To make it global you need to global the variable.

```
from tkinter import *
s = 12
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Program")
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

def clicked():
    #global s
    s = e.get()
    print(s)

button = Button(root,command=clicked,text="ok")
button.pack()
b2 = Button(root, text='print', command=lambda:print(s))
b2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `.place()` instead of `.pack()` and placed my same entry on the same position as it was place before, but this time if value changes as you click on button OK.
Use `e.insert(0,"Value")` to insert any value in a entry.
This worked for me. Also let me know did it worked for you as well?

```
from tkinter import *
s = 12
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("Program")
e = Entry(root)
e.place(relx=0.1, rely = 0.1)

def clicked():
    e = Entry(root)
    e.insert(0, s)
    e.place(relx=0.1, rely = 0.1)

button = Button(root,command=clicked,text="ok")
button.place(relx=0.4, rely = 0.2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Every time ok is clicked a new Entry is created.  It's placed to cover the previous ones.  It's generally better to update an existing widget than constantly add widgets in this situation.